# How to use lambda to select a sub list using async in c# Mongodb driver

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I am writing an application that uses nested object lists heavily and I am struggling to find a way to retrieve sub lists that I am happy with.

I am fairly new to async programming and would like to do something like the following but I can't seem to figure out a way without breaking it into two separate calls. Having to get all the sub results only to filter them down to what I want after the fact doesn't seem all that efficient.

```
baseObj 
{ 
    string ID; 
    string name; 
    List<subObj> subObjList
    {
        string ID; 
        string desc;
        bool deleted;
    }; 
}
```

I know this doesn't work, but I feel like its something small that I could change to make it work, but I have no idea where to start.

```
List<subObj> = await collection.AsQueryable().Where(w=> w.ID == "id").Select(s => s.subObjList.Where(w => w.deleted == false).ToList()).FirstAsync();
```

This does work, but I would think it could be done more efficiently

```
baseObj obj = await collection.AsQueryable().Where(w=> w.ID == "id").firstAsync();
List<subObj> sObjList = obj.subObjList.Where(w => w.deleted == false).ToList();
```

Is there a way to select the sub list in just one query or is it just not possible.

Comment: Does it really have to be a single query?  I often break single queries of this type into multiple queries for clarity anyway, and because you're using a Queryable, it makes no difference at all from a performance perspective.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Maybe I have been missing something all along here, but how does using Queryable prevent multiple statements from being less efficient?

Comment: Queryables don't return a result.  They return an *Expression Tree* that produces an eventual result when compelled to do so.  Each of your queries, when combined, essentially produce a single expression tree, just as individual trees in a binary search tree combine to produce a single tree.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.queryable?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: I learned something new today. Thanks @RobertHarvey

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, just use SelectMany instead of Select:

```
List<subObj> sObjList = collection.AsQueryable()
    .Where(w=> w.ID =="id")
    .SelectMany(x => x.subObjList)
    .Where(w => w.deleted == false)
    .ToList();
```